# Translating Divi booked

Tags: wordpress, poedit

I have to translate my divi booked plugin. Unfourtunately, Loco translate will not work.

On their website, they say it is easily achievable with Poedit. How should i call and where should I place my poedit file then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin is not fully configured for Loco Translate.

To make it work, go to the plugin in Loco Translate.

It will show a template file, it does not know what to do with. 
Click setup in that warning box. There is a template file location input. 
Type in "language/booked.pot" .

This is written from memory, but it should get you going.